# How to download file from FTP with Laravel Storage to the application itself?

Tags: laravel, ftp, laravel-storage

I want to access my Storage, which is FTP (remote server) by default as it is in the config and I want to download a file from there to my application.

If I use `Storage::download('path/to/file')` I get a *Symfony StreamedResponse*, what to my understanding that means i should return this stream to the user to download the file.

So how can I download from this FTP Storage to a folder in my application instead of a third user? Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

```
    Storage::disk('public')->put('foldername/filename.extension', Storage::disk('sftp')->get('sftpfile.extension'));
```